# Undelete messages from kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have mixed retention.ms and delete.retention.ms properties in kafka, with the result that some messages that I'm interested are now in a deleted status. The messages are not deleted from the disk, as the delete.retention.ms property is big enough.

So, I can see that the segment files are on disk, but for kafka the earlies message is only 1 day ago even with files of 4 or 5 months on the directory.

Is there a way to tell kafka to move backwards the "earliest offset" and make those messages available again and not subjected to a possible flush?

Comment: In general, no, you can't undelete data, but if you have the index and segment files, I'd think restarting the broker would cause it to detect those segments

Comment: That doesn't work, so far, the only thing I'm able to do is dump the messages from the files with the kafkadumplog tool, and republish them. Another way could be to create another topic from the files I actually have, but I can't find how.